# Blender transparency does not work properly

Tags: rendering, animation, transparency

I have this text thats textured and ready to be rendered. I want to render it with a transparent background, but, after toggling to png and setting up the transparency in render properties, the rendered image just becomes nothing. Saving the image to computer doesn't do anything either. How would I be able to fix this?

[image: object ready to render in camera view]

[image: nothing gets rendered, other than transparency, ironically]

[image: suspicious these nodes might be doing something]

file:

https://mega.nz/file/6ex0kRSK#WFOshIG7Lpp7dHjhxyAyijKp_Si0yQz5KA8bICbuxh8

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: In the Output panel > Post Processing, disable Sequencer, you must have a track in your video sequencer, it prevents any 3D scene render

Comment: @moonboots Thanks! Haven't tried it out yet. Would not rendering with cycles also be a problem?

Comment: yes, it will be a problem with Eevee as well, just disable the option

Answer (score 1):

In the *Output panel > Post Processing*, disable *Sequencer*, you must have a track in your video sequencer, it prevents any 3D scene render.